# Error in SQL Server query - inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am trying to add Percentile value for each record as new column. But i am getting error in my SQL query. Can anyone please help to solve it.

Error message:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

```
 Select b.* , a.[Rank_1]/count(b.[Date]) * 100 as Percentile from 
  [Country_table1$] b  where [Country] = 'AUSTRALIA' 
  inner join 
   (
 select [MSCI_Price_idx], [Country], rank() OVER (PARTITION BY [Country] 
   ORDER BY [MSCI_Price_idx] DESC) AS [Rank_1]
   from [Country_table1$] 
  GROUP BY [MSCI_Price_idx],[Country] 
  ) a
ON a.[Country] = b.[Country]
```

Comment: Maybe move `where [country] = 'AUSTRALIA'` below your line `ON A.[Country] = b.[Country]` ?

Comment: You should look up the basic syntax for queries. Then you will realize the where clause is completely in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `where` statement in the wrong place. Joins are formally part of the `from` statement and thus come before criteria. To have your criterion at the bottom check the correct table you use the alias.

```
Select b.* , a.[Rank_1]/count(b.[Date]) * 100 as Percentile from 
  [Country_table1$] b
  inner join 
   (
 select [MSCI_Price_idx], [Country], rank() OVER (PARTITION BY [Country] 
   ORDER BY [MSCI_Price_idx] DESC) AS [Rank_1]
   from [Country_table1$] 
  GROUP BY [MSCI_Price_idx],[Country] 
  ) a
ON a.[Country] = b.[Country]  
  where b.[Country] = 'AUSTRALIA'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This Works